# Hide photo and replace another photo in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a question about JavaScript: when the user clicks the jump-down button, the text box opens and the direction of button changes and rotates.

I think I should use two photo. when I click the jump-down button, the first photo hides and the other photo replaces, but I don't know how can I do this in JavaScript (the CSS code for `imageButton2` doesn't work). Here is my code:

```js
$(function () {

    $("#jump_down").click(function () {
        $("#wrapper").slideToggle("slow");
    })

})

var show1=true;
    $('#jump_down').click(function(event) {
        document.getElementById('jump_down').style.visibility = show1 ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('ImageButton2').style.visibility = show1 ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
        show1 = !show1;
    })
```

```css
#jump_down{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(150,190,250,0.7);
    padding: 20px 0;
}

#jump_down img{
    width: 3%;
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

#wrapper{
    background-color: rgba(164,231,246,0.8);
    overflow: hidden;
}

#ImageButton2 img{
    width: 3%;
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<a id="jump_down" href="#wrapper"><img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/427197-200.png" onClick="swapButtons(false)" style="visibility: visible; "></a>

<img src="http://dl.20script.ir/tools/back-up/UpBtn_20Script_2.png" id="ImageButton2" alt="Get Last Digits" style="visibility: hidden;" onClick="swapButtons(true)" />
<div id="wrapper">
           <p>
           Hellow
           </p>
        </div>
        </body>
```

Comment: Why don't you use CSS rotation for that icon without any additional icons & replacing?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mx5ch4r3/36/ you can check this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a pure CSS solution for the image rotation.

Rotate the image once your `#jump_down` div has the class `.open`

```
#jump_down.open img{
 transform:  translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(180deg);
}
```

To toggle the `.open` class, apply `jQuery toggleClass('open')` when `#jump_down` is clicked.

```js
$(function () {

    $("#jump_down").click(function () {
        $( this ).toggleClass("open");
        $("#wrapper").slideToggle("slow");
    })

})
```

```css
#jump_down{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(150,190,250,0.7);
    padding: 20px 0;
}

#jump_down img{
    width: 3%;
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

#jump_down.open img{
 transform:  translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(180deg);
}

#wrapper{
    background-color: rgba(164,231,246,0.8);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<a id="jump_down" href="#wrapper"><img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/427197-200.png" style="visibility: visible; "></a>

<div id="wrapper">
           <p>
           Hellow
           </p>
        </div>
        </body>
```